# Align right menu item inside a stackpanel WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

i'm making a simple WPF application and i'm facing a problem.

I have a StackPanel that contain a Menu and a StackPanel and i'm trying to align certains MenuItem to right but with no success...

I trying to do something like that :

===================================================

FILE .....................................................REDUCE MINIMIZE CLOSE --->MENU

APPTITLE  ---------------------------------------------> Stackpanel

There is another StackPanel that contain both elements to align them Vertically

I tried differents way, with my menu item in a stackpanel or dockpanel...

Here is my MainWindow.xaml :

```
  <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">               
               <Menu materialDesign:RippleAssist.IsDisabled="True" Name="menu" Height="40" Foreground="#FF060000" BorderBrush="#FFED0303">
                    <MenuItem HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Header="_Fichier">
                        <MenuItem Header="_Quitter" Click="ExitButton_Click">
                            <MenuItem.Icon>
                                <Image Source="assets/images/quitter.png"></Image>
                            </MenuItem.Icon>
                        </MenuItem>
                    </MenuItem>

                    <MenuItem Click="minimize_Click" Height="15" Width="19" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,5">
                        <MenuItem.Background>
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="assets/images/minimize.png"/>
                        </MenuItem.Background>
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem Click="maximize_Click" Height="15" Width="19" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="11,10,0,0">
                        <MenuItem.Background>
                            <ImageBrush x:Name="resizeImage" ImageSource="{Binding ResizeImagePath}"/>
                        </MenuItem.Background>
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem  Click="ExitButton_Click" Height="20" Width="19" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="11,10,0,0">
                        <MenuItem.Background>
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="assets/images/close.png"/>
                        </MenuItem.Background>
                    </MenuItem>               
                </Menu>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,14,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <Button Margin="10,0,0,0" Click="scanNetwork_Click" BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
                        <Button.Background>
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="assets/images/756363-200.png"/>
                        </Button.Background>
                    </Button>
                    <TextBlock Text="Machine Sniffer" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignFont}" Foreground="White" Margin="10,0,0,0"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
```

The actual result is something like that :

===================================================

FILE REDUCE MINIMIZE CLOSE --->MENU

APPTITLE  ---------------------------------------------> Stackpanel

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

In StackPanel you are not able to adjust items to te right like you are doing, they not allow alignment in the direction in which they stack.

You can use a Grid or a DockPanel instead:

Example with DockPanel:

```
<DockPanel Width="300">
    <!-- place menu items here and use the VerticalAlignment property like you're doing -->
</DockPanel>
```

Example with Grid:

```
<Grid>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

<!-- place elements here and indicate respective column -->
</Grid>
```